# Selecting unique identifiers with specific values

Tags: sql

I know the title was not very clear so I do apologise - but I need some help.

I have got the table of the data below:

```
   GROUP_ID             CONTACT_ID           MAIN_CONTACT_FLAG
    11000                 28789                     0
    11000                 28049                     1
    21890                 10086                     0
    21890                 10554                     0
    21489                 14785                     0
    21464                 12457                     1
    21654                 14558                     0
```

I need to filter out any group_id's that do not have a contact_id that has the main_contact_flag set to 1

So the desired output would be:

```
   GROUP_ID             CONTACT_ID           MAIN_CONTACT_FLAG
    21890                 10086                     0
    21890                 10554                     0
    21489                 14785                     0
    21654                 14558                     0
```

I have tried the below queries but none of them give me the results I need:

```
SELECT GROUP_ID,MAIN_CONTACT_FLAG FROM Contact_Group_Contacts_T 
WHERE MAIN_CONTACT_FLAG != 0 AND MAIN_CONTACT_FLAG != 1
ORDER BY Group_ID DESC

SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_ID,Main_Group_Contact_BT 
FROM Contact_Group_Contacts_T 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Contact_Group_Contacts_T WHERE MAIN_CONTACT_FLAG IN (0,1))
```

Thanks in advance,
Dan

Comment: What's the data type of `MAIN_CONTACT_FLAG`? You should always include table definition and your RDBMS and version.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Contact_Group_Contacts_T t INNER JOIN
    (SELECT GROUP_ID 
    FROM Contact_Group_Contacts_T 
    GROUP BY GROUP_ID
    HAVING SUM(MAIN_CONTACT_FLAG)=0) sub ON t.GROUP_ID=sub.GROUP_ID
```

Or if you need just group ids

```
    SELECT GROUP_ID 
    FROM Contact_Group_Contacts_T 
    GROUP BY GROUP_ID
    HAVING SUM(MAIN_CONTACT_FLAG)=0
```

UPDATE:

You need to case boolean (bit) to number to be summed

Use SUM(CASE WHEN MAIN_CONTACT_FLAG=0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. I am getting this error if I do either of your queries: Operand data type bit is invalid for sum operator.

Answer (score 1):

Thee are *many* ways.

Your `NOT EXISTS` variant would work in most RDBMS, with this addition:

```
SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_ID
FROM   Contact_Group_Contacts_T T1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT * FROM Contact_Group_Contacts_T T2
   WHERE  T2.GROUP_ID = T1.GROUP_ID  -- the missing piece!
   AND    T2.MAIN_CONTACT_FLAG = 1);
```

In **PostgreSQL**, assuming `MAIN_CONTACT_FLAG` is `boolean NOT NULL`, there is a simple way with the [aggregate function `bool_or()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE)

```
SELECT group_id
FROM   contact_group_contacts_t
GROUP  BY 1
HAVING NOT bool_or(main_contact_flag);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
select * from 
(
    select *,max(MAIN_CONTACT_FLAG) over (partition by GROUP_ID) as final_flag
    from tablename
)
where final_flag=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS:** you can achieve desired output by using subquery

```
select * 
from #tmp
where group_id not in (select distinct group_id from #tmp where main_contact_flag = 1)
```

OR `NOT EXISTS`

```
select t.* 
from #tmp t
where not exists (select 1 
                  from #tmp t1 where t.group_id = t1.group_id and t1.main_contact_flag = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/11116f/11)

```
select * from table1 t1
where not exists
(select 1 from table1 t2
 where t1.group_id=t2.group_id
 and t2.MAIN_CONTACT_FLAG = 1)
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried your query however after some testing, it pulled through group ID's that do have the MAIN_CONTACT_FLAG set to 1 but not showing those records on the output query

Comment: I would suggest you to replicate the same in the fiddle which I gave so I can figure out where is it breaking.